# Going to Canada and transiting through the US

Tags: usa, transit, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

A person with two nationalities, Nationality A from a EU country, and allowed on US VWP, Nationality B from a country not covered by VWP

In Canada - Permanent Resident (but the papers point to Nationality B)

Let's see what TIMATIC has to say:

> - A return/onward ticket (or electronic ticket record) must
>     be **to a final destination country other than Canada**, Mexico
>     or contiguous (adjacent) countries or territories situated
>     in or bordering the Caribbean Sea For details, click here . If
>     passenger holds proof of residence in, **or is transiting the
>     USA to such a country or territory**, an onward/return ticket
>     to that country or territory is accepted.

So, after reading this multiple times it seems it contradicts itself (especially the bold parts)

The question is, would it be possible to transit through USA on Nat. A even if the reason to go to Canada is (in) Nat. B?

Answer (score 2):

Transiting the U.S. is no different from entering the U.S. Or in other words, there is no separate concept of "transiting the U.S." -- you must enter the U.S. and then leave the U.S.

Since you have a VWP nationality, you should use that to enter the U.S. What other nationalities you may have are not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The sense of the quoted statement is that you must hold a return ticket to a country other than Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean - UNLESS you are transiting to one of those countries, or you hold proof of residence in one of those countries, in which case a ticket to that country is acceptable.